# how to use shared element transition in a dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, shared-element-transition

I'm using navigation component. From the RecyclerView in a fragment I want to animate the ImageView to a DialogFragment.

```
sdvPhoto.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("ImageFilePath", image.getAbsolutePath());
                    args.putString("transition_name", "photo_" + getAdapterPosition());

                    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(sdvPhoto, "photo_" + getAdapterPosition());

                    DialogFragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                            .addSharedElement(sdvPhoto, "photo_" + getAdapterPosition())
                            .build();

                    Navigation.findNavController(parentFragment.getView()).navigate(R.id.action_chatFragment_to_imageViewFragment, args, null, extras);
                });
```

And then in the DialogFragment I do this...

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    baseViewFragmentImageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_view, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, baseViewFragmentImageView);
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    if (bundle != null) {
        iv.setPhotoUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(bundle.getString("ImageFilePath"))));
        iv.setTransitionName(bundle.getString("transition_name"));
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(iv, bundle.getString("transition_name"));
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
        transitionSet.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
        transitionSet.addTarget(iv);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transitionSet);
        this.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new ImageTransition());
    }
    return baseViewFragmentImageView;
}
```

This was working for fragment to fragment, but I do not want to do it using DialogFragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DialogFragment` does not support shared element transitions, since Fragment shared element transitions only transition within the same window (vs dialogs, which are a separate window). Navigation does not change this fact, unfortunately.

Comment: Will it work if I do it Fragment to Activity ? I want a full screen ImageViewer with transparent background showing the RecyclerView.
What do you suggest? I don't wanna recreate my RecyclerView since the fragment recreates (with navigation component).

Thanks

Comment: I mean, you need to handle configuration changes and process death recreating your RecyclerView anyways - Navigation isn't any different case than those when it comes to keeping your view state, RecyclerView included (there's just a lot more caveats on general with RecyclerView). I don't think shared elements to dialog themed activities in general are really a tested or supported scenario in any case, but you'd probably have better luck using activity shared element transitions if anything works at all.

Comment: The thing is fragment to fragment it was working but not for the return transition which is another issue I suppose. And the navigation component replaces the previous fragment with the new one, so I cannot have a semi transparent background for the ImageView fragment.

What I will try to do now is to do a fragment transaction using legacy fragment manager way instead of using nav component.

If that doesn't work will, try fragment to activity.

Thanks for your help I will mark this answer as the accepted one as it seems fair for the main question posted.

Comment: Navigation doesn't change how Fragment shared element transitions work, as per my answer.